# Dump two dictionaries in a json file on separate lines

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dump

This is my code:

```
import json

data1 = {"example1":1, "example2":2}
data2 = {"example21":21, "example22":22}

with open("saveData.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data1, outfile)
    json.dump(data2, outfile)
```

The output is this:

> {"example2": 2, "example1": 1}{"example21": 21, "example22": 22}

When I want the output to be  this:

> {"example2": 2, "example1": 1}
>
> {"example21": 21, "example22": 22}

So how do I dump data1 and data2 dictionaries to the same json file on two separate lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to write a newline between them; just add a `.write('\n')` call:

```
with open("saveData.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data1, outfile)
    outfile.write('\n')
    json.dump(data2, outfile)
```

This produces valid [JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org/) output; load the data again by iterating over the lines in the file and using `json.loads()`:

```
with open("saveData.json", "r") as infile:
    data = []
    for line in infile:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`, when i try to load it I mean... The dumping worked just like I wanted

Comment: @Caz: that's because I made a dumb typo; I explicitly stated you need to use `json.loads()` then promptly forgot to include the trailing `s` in the code sample. Corrected now.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that `json.load()` was supposed to be `json.load()` , but now if I print it it says `[{u'example2':2...` , where does the "u" come from?

Comment: @Caz: JSON text is always Unicode text. The `u'...'` tells you that you have Unicode text strings. Python 2 will transparently encode those to ASCII bytestrings when you mix string types.

Comment: Is there any way I can get rid of it? And/Or can I load back from the json file to data1 and data2? (without "u")

Comment: @Caz: no, and you really don't need to worry about it unless you have non-ASCII data. At which point you really should use Unicode throughout anyway. Python 3 makes strings Unicode strings by default. You probably should move to Python 3 as all support for Python 2 ends in 18 months time.