# Python: Parse text file to a formatted json file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a text file and need to extract some information and write it into a JSON file in a formatted way.

**Text file:**

```
Jul 23 06:43:06 localhost : [file.download][Informational][0X1013] Attempting connection to https://fileserver/file/abcdefg
Jul 23 06:43:06 localhost : [file.download][Informational][0X800F0000] CA file error
```

**Required JSON formatted way:**

```
{'Timestamp': 'Jul 23 06:43:06 ', 'Source': 'file.download', 'Level': 'Informational', 'code': '0X1013', 'messages': 'Attempting connection to https://fileserver/file/abcdefg'}
{'Timestamp': 'Jul 23 06:43:06 ', 'Source': 'file.download', 'Level': 'Informational', 'code': '0X800F0000', 'messages': 'CA file error'}
```

Code:

```
import json

with open('c:\Temp\log.txt', 'r') as data:
    result = [ {
            'Timestamp': line.strip().split('localhost : ')[0],
            'Source': line.strip().split('[')[1].rstrip(']'),
            'Level': line.strip().split('[')[2].rstrip(']'),
            'code': line.strip().split('[')[3].split(']')[0],
            'messages': line.strip().split('[')[3].split(']')[1].strip()
            } for line in data]

print(result)

with open('output.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json.dumps(result))
```

Output:

```
[{'Timestamp': 'Jul 23 06:43:06 ', 'Source': 'file.download', 'Level': 'Informational', 'code': '0X1013', 'messages': 'Attempting connection to https://fileserver/file/abcdefg'}, {'Timestamp': 'Jul 23 06:43:06 ', 'Source': 'file.download', 'Level': 'Informational', 'code': '0X800F0000', 'messages': 'CA file error'}]
```

Questions:

What must I do in order to make code output to be the same as the "Required JSON formatted way"?

Comment: What needs to change?

Comment: Please provide a sample for the `.txt` file

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I manage to get the formatted line.

Answer (score 2):

think this works (help from [Dump two dictionaries in a json file on separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232080/dump-two-dictionaries-in-a-json-file-on-separate-lines))

```
import json

with open('c:\Temp\log.txt', 'r') as data:
    result = [ {
            'Timestamp': line.strip().split('localhost : ')[0],
            'Source': line.strip().split('[')[1].rstrip(']'),
            'Level': line.strip().split('[')[2].rstrip(']'),
            'code': line.strip().split('[')[3].split(']')[0],
            'messages': line.strip().split('[')[3].split(']')[1].strip()
            } for line in data]


with open('output.json', 'w') as json_file:

    json.dump(result[0], json_file)
    json_file.write('\n')
    json.dump(result[1], json_file)
```